# H1b: Is it safe to move to different team (internal transfer) within same company before Oct 1st?

Tags: h1-visa, usa

My question is pretty obvious as mentioned in the title: currently I am on OPT, but my H1B just got selected from the lottery. Probably will be valid on October this year.

The thing is, I currently do not feel comfortable working with my current team, so I am planning to move to a different team in the same company (similar job function, but different address). Will it affect my H1B visa? And do I need to do something with my lawyer about this?

Comment: Have you asked your lawyer about this? What did they say?